# Accidentally changed routers subnet mask to 0.0.0.0

Tags: wireless-networking, netmask

I tried to do it to try one thing, needless to say it was a bad idea. This means I now don't have internet access and cannot log in into router admin page `192.168.0.1` to change the settings back. It just keeps loading until it says the website is unavailable.

This is the info of my PC now

```
IP address: 192.168.0.17
Diffusion address: 255.255.255.255
Subnet mask: 0.0.0.0
Default gateway: 192.168.0.1
```

And the primary and secondary DNS.

What can I do to restore back to having /24 mask?

Comment: were you messing with the DHCP pool when you put in the bad subnet, and are we looking at a PCs IP infoformation? if so, just set the computer to use a static IP, and set it to 192.168.0.17 with a mask of 255.255.255.0. then attempt to access the page again.

Comment: And if that doesn't work, reset the router's configuration.

Comment: Resetting the configuration did the work. I tried @FrankThomas answer editing the `/etc/network/interface` file but I kept getting lots kind of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, if your attempts to reestablish communication with the router fail, you should reset its configuration.

A subnet mask of 0.0.0.0 is effectively invalid as it causes the so-configured device to act as though other networks (e.g. The Internet) don't exist. Most routers will refuse to accept this value for that reason.